# How to deal with "Cannot modify header information" in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I get "Cannot modify header information" error with this code.

This is my login.php:

```
<?php include("connection.php"); ?>
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION["session_username"])){
header("Location: intropage.php");
}

if(isset($_POST["login"])){
```

sometimes i get "please enter login and password" all the time.

```
if(!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$query =mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE password='".$password."'");
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows!=0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $dbusername = $row["username"];
        $dbpassword = $row["password"];
    }
if($username == $dbusername && $password == $dbpassword) {
    $_SESSION["session_username"] = $username;
    header("Location: intropage.php");
}else{
    echo "Incorrect login or password";
}
}else{
    echo "Please enter login and password";
}
}
}
?>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
```

Comment: As an aside, do _not_  use this code in production. It has serious security errors that will permit anyone to log in as anyone else. In particular, it has SQL injection vulnerabilities. It also stores passwords in plain text, which will compound your users' security problems in the likely event you get hacked.

Answer (score -1):

You are sending new empty line to user browser in that part of your code so you can't send headers after that.

```
<?php include("connection.php"); ?>
<?php
```

Comment: Can you add into this what the fix would be?

Comment: Assuming connection.php doesn't output anything to the display, remove the closing `?>` after it as well as the opening `<?php` just below it.

If connection.php does write to the screen you'll have to move your redirect above it.